# WebStorm run configuration - package.json path relative to project directory

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, webstorm, yarnpkg, jetbrains-ide

**Question:** In WebStorm's npm run configuration: How to make the `package.json` path relative to project directory?

**Goal:** To be able to share the run configuration in VCS, it must not depend on where the project is on my machine.

**Screenshot:** I.e., I want to change `~\WebStormProjects\x-nest\` to `PROJECT_DIR\`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**package.json** field doesn't support variables; but you do not need to use macros or do anything at all to make configurations shareable, this case is handled automatically: if you look inside the `.idea/workspace.xml` (or `.idea\runConfigurations\<config name>.xml` if **Share through VCS** is enabled for it) file you'll notice that IDE stores this path as `$PROJECT_DIR$/path/to/package.json`, like:

`<package-json value="$PROJECT_DIR$/package.json" />`

So you can safely keep this `.xml` file under Version Control and your colleagues will have the correct path to the file even if local path to project is different.